# How to find out what a oracle process is currently doing

Tags: oracle, process

I have an Oracle process which is running with 100% CPU since hours.

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
75508 oracle    20   0  102.1g   1.7g  39284 R 100.0  1.1 399:52.21 oracle_75508_mp

Is there any possibility to show what especially this process is currently doing?

Thanks in advance :)

Regards,
Steffen

Comment: The v$session view in the database should help you figure it out. It will identify active sessions (including background processes) and show you which SQL they are executing, what they are waiting on, etc. Depending on the version of Oracle you are running, you may also have access to the Enterprise Manager Express console, which will show you a lot more detail about what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find out everything you need to know with the help of V$SESSION and V$PROCESS.

It seems that you already know your PID. With that PID, you can use the following SELECT Statement and identify the SQL_ID.

```
select sid,serial#,username,sql_id,schemaname,osuser,process,machine,port,program,type,paddr
from v$session
where PADDR = (select ADDR from V$PROCESS where SPID = 'YOURPID')
```

With the SQL_ID known, you can go and retrieve the performed action from within V_$SQLAREA. This system view will provide you with the exact statement which is currently running.

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.V_$SQLAREA WHERE sql_id='SQL_ID_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_SELET';
```